# integrating facebook login with restful authentication for rails 3x

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

"some blog and stack-overflow even says that rails 3 dont have work with rails3 for restful-authentication", it may be older posts.

```
So I've gone through several tutorials but nothing found to be working.
```

the error on:

Macbook:Project user$ rails generate xd_receiver
Could not find generator xd_receiver.

so i found the errors and try to fix it but it will prompt for other errors.
And Then found some update for restful-authentication to work with facebook login,
It also cant fix the errors.
then error on:

Macbook:Project user$ rails generate xd_receiver
/Sha/Todayswork/Ruby On Rails/Project/vendor/plugins/facebooker/lib/facebooker/adapters/adapter_base.rb:6:in `<class:Adapter
Base>': uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions (NameError)
        from /Sha/Todayswork/Ruby On Rails/Project/vendor/plugins/facebooker/lib/facebooker/adapters/adapter_base.rb:3:in`<
module:Facebooker>'
        from /Sha/Todayswork/Ruby On Rails/Project/vendor/plugins/facebooker/lib/facebooker/adapters/adapter_base.rb:1:in `<
top (required)>'
        from /Sha/Todayswork/Ruby On Rails/Project/vendor/plugins/facebooker/lib/facebooker.rb:259:in`'
        from /Sha/Todayswork/Ruby On Rails/Project/vendor/plugins/facebooker/init.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Sha/Todayswork/Ruby On Rails/Project/vendor/plugins/facebooker/rails/init.rb:1:in`block in '
        from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/plugin.rb:81:in `eval'
        from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/plugin.rb:81:in`block in '
        from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
        from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in`run'
        from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializ
ers'
        from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in`each'
        from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
        from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in`initialize!'
        from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
        from /Sha/Todayswork/Ruby On Rails/Project/config/environment.rb:5:in`'
        from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require'
        from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in`require_environment!'
        from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in`require'
        from script/rails:6:in `'

Thanks for any response,
And
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

would look into OmniAuth. just used and was painless to integrate. See railscasts for simple auth with OmniAuth